# How to draw a complete circle in iOS with UIBezierPathwithArcCenter?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, swift, uibezierpath

I want the startAngle to be at 90 degrees which is π / 2, so I figured if I made the endAngle 90 degrees then it would just make a complete circle, but instead nothing is drawn.

When I put the start & end angle at different degrees as shown below, the path is drawn, but it's not a full circle.

Heres the code I'm using so far, but I can't seem to figure out what the endAngle should be if the startAngle is 90 degrees in order to draw a complete circle.

Can anyone help?

```
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)
    let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
    let startAngle: CGFloat = 3 * π / 4
    let endAngle: CGFloat = π / 4

    var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
                               radius: bounds.width / 2 - arcWidth / 2,
                           startAngle: startAngle,
                             endAngle: endAngle,
                            clockwise: true)


    path.lineWidth = arcWidth
    path.lineCapStyle = kCGLineCapRound
    counterColor.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To draw a full circle, start angle and end angle must differ by
2π. If you want the start angle to be π/2 then you would choose

```
let startAngle = CGFloat(M_PI/2)
let endAngle = CGFloat(M_PI/2 + 2.0*M_PI)
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Simple but great explanation.

Comment: So simple, yet so elegant. Perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create a complete circle using that method, you must ask it to draw 2π radians.

```
import XCPlayground
import UIKit

let π = CGFloat(M_PI)
let bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 300)
let arcWidth = CGFloat(6)

let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.width / 2, y: bounds.height / 2)
let radius: CGFloat = max(bounds.width, bounds.height)
let startAngle: CGFloat = π / 2
let endAngle: CGFloat = startAngle + 2 * π

var path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center,
    radius: bounds.width / 2 - arcWidth / 2,
    startAngle: startAngle,
    endAngle: endAngle,
    clockwise: true)
XCPCaptureValue("path", path)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know your question is specifically asking for `UIBezierPathwithArcCenter`. 
But why not use `bezierPathWithOvalInRect` if all you want is to draw a circle?

```
CGRect circleLayerRect = CGRectMake(20, 20, 50, 50);

CAShapeLayer *circleLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer]; //Create the layer
[circleLayer setPath:[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:circleLayerRect] CGPath]]; //Set the rect.
[[self.view layer] addSublayer:circleLayer]; //Add the layer
```

You failed to specify the circle's properties, but you may add and change the stroke and fill color like so:

```
[circleLayer setStrokeColor:[[UIColor redColor] CGColor]];
[circleLayer setFillColor:[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor]];
```